# What's purpose of ErrorKind::__Nonexhaustive?

Tags: rust

`std::io::ErrorKind` has a variant `__Nonexhaustive`.
I don't know what is the problem if this variant doesn't exist.

What's purpose of this variant?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is designed to allow the `ErrorKind` enum to be expanded in future, by forcing any `match` statements in stable code to have a catch-all `_` arm.

Specifically, [the variant is marked unstable](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/241a9d0ddf99fd40d273c615e9b1e8ce6052d94a/src/libstd/io/error.rs#L163-L166) and so cannot be referred to on the stable channel, and so the compiler rejects code like

```
fn foo(x: Error) {
    match x.kind() {
        ErrorKind::NotFound => {}
        ErrorKind::PermissionDenied => {}
        ErrorKind::ConnectionRefused => {}
        ErrorKind::ConnectionReset => {}
        ErrorKind::ConnectionAborted => {}
        ErrorKind::NotConnected => {}
        ErrorKind::AddrInUse => {}
        ErrorKind::AddrNotAvailable => {}
        ErrorKind::BrokenPipe => {}
        ErrorKind::AlreadyExists => {}
        ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {}
        ErrorKind::InvalidInput => {}
        ErrorKind::InvalidData => {}
        ErrorKind::TimedOut => {}
        ErrorKind::WriteZero => {}
        ErrorKind::Interrupted => {}
        ErrorKind::Other => {}
        ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof => {}
        ErrorKind::UnexpectedEOF => {}
        ErrorKind::__Nonexhaustive => {}
    }
}
```

```
<anon>:24:9: 24:35 error: use of unstable library feature 'io_error_internals': better expressed through extensible enums that this enum cannot be exhaustively matched against (see issue #0)
<anon>:24         ErrorKind::__Nonexhaustive => {}
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If this code compiled successfully on stable Rust, then adding a variant to `ErrorKind` in a future version would break any code that had `match`s like the above, and breaking stable code is bad. The code breaks because matches in Rust must be exhaustive, that is, they must cover every possibility, in some way, and thus adding a variant would mean that possibility isn't covered.

Instead, programmers must write:

```
fn foo(x: Error) {
    match x.kind() {
        ErrorKind::NotFound => {}
        ErrorKind::PermissionDenied => {}
        ErrorKind::ConnectionRefused => {}
        ErrorKind::ConnectionReset => {}
        ErrorKind::ConnectionAborted => {}
        ErrorKind::NotConnected => {}
        ErrorKind::AddrInUse => {}
        ErrorKind::AddrNotAvailable => {}
        ErrorKind::BrokenPipe => {}
        ErrorKind::AlreadyExists => {}
        ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {}
        ErrorKind::InvalidInput => {}
        ErrorKind::InvalidData => {}
        ErrorKind::TimedOut => {}
        ErrorKind::WriteZero => {}
        ErrorKind::Interrupted => {}
        ErrorKind::Other => {}
        ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof => {}
        ErrorKind::UnexpectedEOF => {}
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

This means that any variants added to `ErrorKind` in future (e.g. new error possibilities for new IO functions) will fall under the `_` arm, and thus existing stable code won't break.

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of this hidden variant is to prevent you from writing something like this (which doesn't compile precisely because of the presence of `__Nonexhaustive`):

```
use std::io::ErrorKind;

fn main() {
    let error_kind: ErrorKind = unimplemented!();
    match error_kind {
        ErrorKind::NotFound => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::PermissionDenied => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::ConnectionRefused => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::ConnectionReset => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::ConnectionAborted => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::NotConnected => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::AddrInUse => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::AddrNotAvailable => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::BrokenPipe => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::AlreadyExists => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::WouldBlock => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::InvalidInput => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::InvalidData => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::TimedOut => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::WriteZero => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::Interrupted => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::Other => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::UnexpectedEOF => unimplemented!(),
        ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof => unimplemented!(),
        // note: no wildcard match arm here
    };
}
```

The reason *why* the developers of the standard library don't want you to do this is to retain the ability to add variants to `ErrorKind` in the future. The `__Nonexhaustive` variant prevents you from doing an exhaustive match by simply handling each individual variant; you **must** have a wildcard arm to have an exhaustive match.

In Rust, the `match` expression requires that all possible patterns for the expression being matched on have a corresponding arm, so that the `match` expression always has a well-defined, explicit value. A `match` that covers all patterns is called an **exhaustive** match. With `enum`s, Rust lets us simply list all variants. For example, with [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html), which only has 2 variants, named `None` and `Some`, we can write:

```
fn main() {
    let option: Option<()> = unimplemented!();
    match option {
        None => unimplemented!(),
        Some(()) => unimplemented!(),
    };
}
```

This `match` compiles fine, because it covers all possible patterns for `option`. However, if the `Option` type gained another variant, then suddenly *your* code wouldn't compile anymore, because it would no longer be exhaustive. Naturally, this wouldn't make sense for `Option`, so the `Option` type doesn't play the "nonexhaustive" game. But if `__Nonexhaustive` wasn't there, adding a variant to `ErrorKind` would be a breaking change; any code that did an exhaustive match (without wildcards) on an `ErrorKind` would suddenly stop compiling. This code might be in a crate that your application depends on, and that breakage could prevent you from upgrading Rust until *that* crate is fixed!